# go to specific page on button click in asp gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

**I am trying to implement GO TO page.Means when i enter any page number in text box "txtGoToPage" and clicking button "btnGo" it should take me to that page.**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblGoToPage" runat="server" Text="Go To Page : "></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGoToPage" runat="server" Width="47px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="btnGo_Click" />

<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="gv_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gv_RowEditing" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnRowCreated="gv_RowCreated" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="gv_RowUpdating" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_PageIndexChanging" GridLines="Both" CssClass="GridViewStyle" class="ui-widget-content" Style="width: 100%; padding: 2px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        <EditRowStyle CssClass="GridViewEditRow" />
                                        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                        <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" HeaderText="ID">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Correct">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCorrect" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("correct") %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCorrect" runat="server" Width="40px" Text='<%#Eval("correct") %>' />
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblComments" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("comments") %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" TextMode="multiline" Width="50px" Columns="50" Rows="5" Text='<%#Eval("comments") %>' />
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>

                                        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last"
                                            Mode="Numeric" PageButtonCount="20" PreviousPageText="Previous" />

                                    </asp:GridView>
```

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample answer:

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt16(txtGoToPage.Text) -1; //since PageIndex starts from 0 by default.
    txtGoToPage.Text = "";
    GridView1.DataBind()
}
```

Comment: an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property exception.@Mohan Srinivas

Comment: I think you are calling an instance method  from a static method (Main). To correct this error, either (1) declare a variable of type program and then call the method or (2) add 'static' to the declaration of method.